# Displaying Table using models in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to create a project management kind of app.
Now I have the project model like in this image

[image: Project model page]

When i save it, i can able to get username and time.

Now. In the same page below I want to display Table where user can add, edit. just like in this image

[image: project details]
How can i do that?

Do we want to create database table and call here? 
I couldn't find any thread on this post.

Answer (score 6):

You may want either [`AdminInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) or [`list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) Django features:

1. If you have linked models, say a `Project` and a `Product`, which is linked to `Project`, you can make your product editable as inlines:

   ```
   class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
       model = Product

   class Project(admin.ModelAdmin):
       model = Project
       inlines = [ProductInline, ]
   ```
2. If you have a standalone table, say, `Product`, you can make its list to be editable:

   ```
   class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       model = Product
       list_display = ['quantity', 'description', 'tax_rate', ] 
       list_editable = ['quantity', 'description', 'tax_rate', ]
   ```

Comment: Apparantly, in you later example you should set list_display_links = None