# how can I store multiple select (select2) data in mysql php?

Tags: multidimensional-array, jquery-select2

I have tried to store the data but I am not getting the proper output.

```
 for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST["service_product"]); $i++) 
{ 
*This count is 3*
for ($a =0 ; $a < count($_POST["service_provider"]); $a++)
              {
             *This count is 4*
              //insert query...
               } 

}
```

---

I'm getting this output:

### 1
2
4
10

### 1
2
4
10

### 1
2
4
10

### This is the desired output:

### 1
2

### 4

### 10

because in
the first-row  there are two select values.
the second-row there is only one select value.
and
the third row contains only one...
and so on...[this is the image for reference so that you guys can understand well ..may be I have not explained well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLnJ7.png)

Comment: It's not a limitation of PHP or Select2 specifically, it's just that submitting a webform combines together values of different controls with the same name. [Django inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810808/displaying-table-using-models-in-django-admin) has forms-as-table-rows like this, and do something equivalent to `INLINE_ROW1_service_provider` and `INLINE_ROW2_service_provider`. The code to take that input format and unpack it into rows is obviously a bit trickier than what you have here.

Comment: Since this is commonly needed, you probably ought to find existing code that can do it for you instead of writing from scratch. I don't know the PHP world well, but searching around about table forms and PHP frameworks got me to https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/basic/inATable